# How to put an IF statement in a JOIN in SQL query (sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query where  I'm getting all the registers between two values(CurrentValue and NextValue) for each range, the thing is when I get to the last value... ther is no NextValue for getting  the registers for the Current Value Something Like this

```
CV       NV
10245<-->10369 = (10263,10333,10357)
10963<-->11052 = (10964,11000,11022)
11300<-->"NoNextValue" = (Still needing the Values after 11300)
```

What I want to know If there is a way for putting a If statement in the ON comparation in the JOIN FOR example

I have this

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mif.Row1),
*
FROM DispatchFianzas.dbo.MisFianzas mif
)

SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT b.*, CTE.FolioTrip as CurrentValue, nex.FolioTrip as NextValue
  FROM UltraTrips.dbo.Bails b
  LEFT JOIN  CTE ON CTE.bail = b.bail
  LEFT JOIN  CTE nex  ON nex.rownum  = CTE.rownum + 1 
  )a
  LEFT JOIN  DispatchBails.dbo.Trips t 
  ON t.trip  BETWEEN a.CurrentValue AND a.NextValue ) c
```

as you can see in the last line  " ON t.trip BETWEEN a.CurrentValue AND a.NextValue" I'm using this for making the JOIN but I Would like something Like this

```
ON IF(a.NextValue IS NOT NULL)
   BEGIN
   t.trip  BETWEEN a.CurrentValue AND a.NextValue
   END
   ELSE
   t.trip > a.CurrentValue
```

, so... can you tell me a way of doing this?, thanks

Comment: There is [`IIF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) function

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can use a case statement in a  join, you'll need to use an OR.

```
ON
(a.NextValue is not null 
and
t.trip  BETWEEN a.CurrentValue AND a.NextValue)
or
t.trip > a.CurrentValue
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Case clause can be used to replace the IF statement you wrote and should be valid for SQL

```
On 1 = CASE WHEN a.NextValue IS NOT NULL 
                 AND t.trip between a.CurrentValues AND a.NextValue THEN 1
            WHEN a.NextValue IS NULL AND t.trip > a.CurrentValue THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
       END
```

Just check the performance of the select as I'm not sure how it will behave with indexes.